# dnx-watch is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: .net, environment-variables, asp.net-core, dnx, dnu

I've tried to install the command dnx-watch through the command prompt so that I don't need to restart my server when file changes occur in my project. 
After running the following command `dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher` it runs and installs the packages. Notice the following line:

```
"The following commands were installed:" dnx-watch
```

Then when I'm trying to run it, it says it's not recognized as an internal or external command?

And when I try to uninstall the commands using

```
dnu commands uninstall Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher
```

it throws the following:
[image]
Edit: 
When i run dnu list, it lists all the packages but the watcher package has a star before it? Like below:

[image]

Is it not installed correctly?

I'm using 1.0.0-rc1-update2 coreclr x64 btw.

The installation process looks like this: 
[image]

As you can see, it adds the package to my \.dnx path. 
When I runt the command `dnx-watch` inside the folder of the package's (Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher) project.json file, it works.

How do I install it globally?

Finally my Environment variables looks like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit confusing but uninstall takes the command name. So, it should be `dnu commands uninstall dnx-watch`.

Can you please make sure that `%userprofile%/.dnx/bin` is on the PATH and that is has dnx-watch in it?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've edited my question to provide some more information about the problem.

Comment: Can you share the full value of PATH?

Comment: Sorry, It seems like it was the missing variable in the path that was the problem all along. Added the following line to the path %USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin. like you suggested and now it works like a charm. Thank you